# How to add a title and suptitle to each gridspec group

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, matplotlib-gridspec, suptitle

I know I can use `update` to adjust the parameters of a `GridSpec` instance in a matplotlib figure, allowing to arrange multiple gridspec's in a single figure. Much as in this example taken from the matplotlib doc

```
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, :-1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, -1])

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs2[:, :-1])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs2[:-1, -1])
ax6 = plt.subplot(gs2[-1, -1])
```

But how can I give both `gs1` and `gs2` their own common title? Using `suptitle` I only get a common title for the whole figure at once.

Answer (score 5):

Way too late, but just found this thread when searching for the exact same thing, so just leaving this for anyone stumbling across it.

I think @pathoren's Alternative 4) is the way to go, but you can reuse the existing gridspec to create your ghost axis such that it exactly matches the existing ones:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[-1, :-1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[-1, -1])

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:, :-1])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:-1, -1])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[-1, -1])

# Add ghost axes and titles on gs1 and gs2
ax_left = fig.add_subplot(gs1[:])
ax_left.axis('off')
ax_left.set_title('Left title')

ax_right = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:])
ax_right.axis('off')
ax_right.set_title('Right title')

plt.show()
```

Resulting layout:

[image: Resulting layout]

Answer (score 3):

I can think of four ways, all quite ugly.  I do not know if there are any automatic way of setting such things.

The four ugly ways are:

1)  Set the title to the "top" axis-object in each group with `ax.set_title()` (in your case `ax1` and `ax4`).  It works great on the left group, but horrible for the right group...

2) Set one title with `fig.suptitle`, but make a lot of spaces inside the title, and use `horizontalalignment='center'`.

3) Set a text-object manually for each title... (not in the example below, but just look at [matplotlib.text](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html))

4) Create ghost axes, hide everything on them and just use them to set their title...

Below is some example code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[:-1, :])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[-1, :-1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[-1, -1])
ax1.set_title('Left group title')  # Alternative 1)

gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, hspace=0.05)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:, :-1])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[:-1, -1])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs2[-1, -1])
ax4.set_title('Right group title')  # Alternative 1)
# Alternative 2. Note the many white-spaces
fig.suptitle('figure title left                                                   figure title right', horizontalalignment='center')

# Alternative 4)
rect_left = 0, 0, 0.5, 0.8  # lower, left, width, height (I use a lower height than 1.0, to place the title more visible)
rect_right = 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.8
ax_left = fig.add_axes(rect_left)
ax_right = fig.add_axes(rect_right)
ax_left.set_xticks([])
ax_left.set_yticks([])
ax_left.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax_left.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax_left.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax_left.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax_left.set_axis_bgcolor('none')
ax_right.set_xticks([])
ax_right.set_yticks([])
ax_right.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax_right.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax_right.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax_right.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax_right.set_axis_bgcolor('none')
ax_left.set_title('Ghost left title')
ax_right.set_title('Ghost right title')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your ideas. I like the ghost solution best. Still, it would be logical if the `GridSpec` instance actually had the properties of a sort of "subfigure" allowing to set a `suptitle` per `GridSpec` instance. Wouldnt you agree ?

Comment: I do not know if it already exist or not.  However making such a thing as general as it has to be seem extremely tricky and I doubt that has been done.  My best tip for applications like these is to just do it manually, as I showed :)

Comment: It looks like alternative 2 isn't complete